# Day difference, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have Dataframe "Report" with Date column "Next release date" and I want to calculate no. of days between today and the 'Next release date'

```
>>> Report['Next release date']
1    2020-02-11
2    2019-08-12
3    2019-08-13
```

Column Type of 'Next release date' is 'str'

```
Report['Next release date'] = pd.to_datetime(Report['Next release date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
Report['Date_Diff'] = Report['Next release date'] - datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Above script gives zero for date '2019-08-13' - today(), actual difference is 1 day, but it gives zero
and for "2019-08-12" gives '-1' result instead of zero

Please help on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Timestamp.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html) for replace times to `00:00:00`:

```
print (pd.to_datetime('today').floor('D'))
2019-08-12 00:00:00

Report['Date_Diff'] = Report['Next release date'] - pd.to_datetime('today').floor('D')
print (Report)
  Next release date Date_Diff
1        2020-02-11  183 days
2        2019-08-12    0 days
3        2019-08-13    1 days
```